# Entity Framework Vs MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am a Asp.net developer and due to new advancements I am confused between MVC and Entity Framework.I would like to know which is the best option to study first EF or MVC

Comment: It's not a matter of one or the other.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417362/asp-net-mvc-models-vs-entity-framework-models

Comment: The two of these EF and MVC work together if you use it, you just study MVc and then use EF with it. These two are different technologies

Answer (score 3):

The two are completely different and have different purposes.

MVC (Model View Controller) is a programmatical pattern used for building applications. Microsoft have a a framework called ASP.Net MVC which is their implementation of it for building MVC websites.

Entity Framework (EF) is an ORM (Object Relational Mapping) tool. This is used primarily for simplifying the data access layer of an application. This can be used in conjunction with ASP.Net MVC.

Personally, I would read about ASP.Net MVC first. This is because you can then use any one of several ORMs with it, including NHibernate and Linq2SQL, the latter being very lightweight and a perfect place to start.

Answer (score 0):

I think they "must" works toghether to get the best. Entity framework, you can think of it as a way to access the database (in an object-oriented fashion). While Asp .NET MVC (which let you choose how to handle the model part, so you can easily use EF) is a framework to create a web application; you can think of it as something that will help you create html pages. As I've stated before, you can easily use entity framework as the M part of mvc if you need to interact with a database.

I suggest you to study MVC first because will give more results (they are something that you can see), then EF. However this is a totally subjective thing.

The most "student" approach is to study EF first and then mvc, but in this case you won't see any real result 'till you studied a bit of MVC.

Hope this helps in any way.